# Split array to strings

Tags: ios

```
(
    56435614315645164,
        {
            data = (
             {
               "created_time" = "2014-01-20T16:40:22+0000";
                id = "277617849058209";
                message = "abcdefght";
             },
    }
```

}

I have this array(at index 0) in iOS. How do I split this array into strings? The results should look like this:

```
string 1=56435614315645164;

    string2={
            data = (
             {
               "created_time" = "2014-01-20T16:40:22+0000";
                id = "277617849058209";
                message = "abcdefght";
             },
    }
```

I would like then split string 2 as:

```
ssting1=data=

sstring2=created time=

sstring3=id=

sstring4=message=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your post you need Deserialization in case you are using JSON
reas the following tutorials for that

[How to deserialize json object and assign to a NSDictionary in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195245/how-to-deserialize-json-object-and-assign-to-a-nsdictionary-in-ios)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

If you are not using JSON simply use the dictionary to store those values and manipulate as your need